# Using ñ in mysql query is not working using this approach

Tags: mysql, utf-8, where-clause

if its not ñ I'm getting the right result but when I'm using it 
**UNDEFINED VARIABLE.**

here's my approach to search the $location
and all Collation and operation in database is SET to "utf8_general_ci"

```
                  <?php
    /*$location = $_GET['location'];*/
    $location = $_GET['location'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM list WHERE loc = '".$location."'");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    $title1=$row['title'];
    $fname=$row['fname'];
    $mname=$row['mname'];
    $lname=$row['lname'];
    $addr1=$row['addr'];
    $post1=$row['position'];
    $location=$row['loc'];
    }
    ?>
```

my connection in db

```
<?php
  include('connect.php');
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'xxx'; 

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

Comment: You should not mix functions of different mysql modules, `mysql_real_escape_string` is not part of mysqli or PDO (I'm not exactly sure which one you use). Beside that `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated, it requires a link identifier `[...]If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments.[...]` as of that it will try to open an additional mysql connection. Instead of inserting the values directly to the query,  you should use `?` placeholders.

Comment: I update my post and use this. this approach works if there's no involved of ñ in finding the loc. ubt I wanted this work also when using ñ in query

Comment: I didn't say you should omit the escaping, but to use the `?`  placeholder instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`. How to use it depends on if you use `PDO` or `mysqli`. The query would look like this: `SELECT * FROM list WHERE loc = ?` then. Your problem is most likely that the encoding set for your **connection** (not the table) does not match the encoding of the data you get in your `$_GET`. What is the encoding of your webpage, is it also utf8? Do you use mysqli or pdo?

Comment: Let's see the `SELECT` after the substitution.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated mysql_* interface; switch to mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: @t.niese I added my db connection I'm using PDO. I'm using UTF8 encoding and all the database where set to utf_general

Comment: @RickJames I'm using PDO please check my update hope you can help me.

Comment: The connection needs to establish that your client characters are utf8.

Comment: Charset problems are not easy to debug, without direct access to the db. Could you add the output you get for the sql query `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE 'character_%'` in `php` (it is important that you do this query in your script and **not** e.g. in phpMyAdmin). The problem that either the encoding of `$location` doe snot match the encoding of the connection, or that you initially already saved that data with a wrong encoding in the database.